# How to pivot on multiple columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database, pivot-table

I have the following table `[EMPLOYEE]`:

| Name | Role | Billed$ | Revenue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Joe | Sales Mgr | $500 | $600 |
| Joe | VP | $800 | $900 |
| Angel | Sales Mgr | $100 | $200 |
| Angel | VP | $300 | $400 |
| Chad | Sales Mgr | $400 | $300 |
| Chad | VP | $600 | $100 |

How do I query the table using pivot and perhaps cross apply to get the following result:

| Name | Sales Mgr Billed | Sales Mgr Revenue | VP Billed | VP Revenue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Joe | $500 | $600 | $800 | $900 |
| Angel | $100 | $200 | $300 | $400 |
| Chad | $400 | $300 | $600 | $100 |

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
SELECT 
    Name, [Sales Mgr] AS 'Sales Mgr Billed', [VP] AS 'VP Billed'
FROM
    (SELECT 
         Name, Role, Billed$, Revenue 
     FROM 
         EMPLOYEE) src
PIVOT
    (SUM(Billed$)
        FOR Role IN ( [Sales Mgr], [VP])
    ) AS pvBilled
PIVOT
    (SUM(Revenue)
         FOR Role IN ( [Sales Mgr], [VP])
    ) AS pvRevenue
```

Answer (score 1):

For these tasks, i've found conditional aggregation to work quite nicely:

```sql
with cte as (
    select *
    from (
    VALUES  (N'Joe', N'Sales Mgr', N'$500', N'$600')
    ,   (N'Joe', N'VP', N'$800', N'$900')
    ,   (N'Angel', N'Sales Mgr', N'$100', N'$200')
    ,   (N'Angel', N'VP', N'$300', N'$400')
    ,   (N'Chad', N'Sales Mgr', N'$400', N'$300')
    ,   (N'Chad', N'VP', N'$600', N'$100')
) t (Name,Role,Billed$,Revenue)
)
SELECT Name
,   max(case when role = 'sales mgr' then billed$ end) as SalesBilled
,   max(case when role = 'sales mgr' then revenue end) AS SalesRevenued
,   max(case when role = 'VP' then billed$ end) AS VPBilled
,   max(case when role = 'VP' then revenue end) AS VPRevenued
from    cte
group by name
```

The `MAX(CASE WHEN something then value END)` construct creates columns from rows by matching them inside the CASE WHEN.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to union the rows with billed value and revenue value and then applying pivot on the resultant union subquery. Below is the query

```sql
select Billed.Name,Billed.[Sales Mgr Billed],[Sales Mgr Revenue],[VP Billed], [VP Revenue] from 
(
     SELECT Name, Role + ' ' + 'Billed' AS Role, Billed$ FROM EMPLOYEE
     UNION ALL
     SELECT Name, Role + ' ' + 'Revenue' AS Role, Revenue FROM EMPLOYEE
) as p
PIVOT(
      SUM(Billed$)
      FOR Role IN ( [Sales Mgr Billed], [VP Billed],[Sales Mgr Revenue], [VP Revenue])) AS Billed
```

**Output:**

| Name | Sales Mgr Billed | Sales Mgr Revenue | VP Billed | VP Revenue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Angel | 100 | 200 | 300 | 400 |
| Chad | 400 | 300 | 600 | 100 |
| Joe | 500 | 600 | 800 | 900 |

[demo@fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Z9HkZbFX)

Comment: Thank you. This is extremely helpful.